# Cannot connect to celery signals from django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the default django integration from the celery docs.

Also just added

```py
@before_task_publish.connect(weak=False)
def before_task_publish_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.error(f'Args {args}')
    logger.error(f'Kwargs {kwargs}')
```

Running in the shell:

> debug_task.delay()

There is no logging or breakpoint catching in pycharm. I do not think it connects to celery, but I do not know how to check. What am I missing?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question/problem is. You're calling `.delay()` then nothing happens? Is your celery worker running?

Comment: Yes the celery worker is running. I'm expecting the before_task_publish to receive a connection from celery. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#basics